# Why does I always get "GET: 403 Forbidden " for default-target-url and AJAX call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using Spring MVC security for my webapp. The user goes to localhost/CT/home  and in that page enters username and password which goes to /login. If successfully verified goes to /loginCheck , else if authentication failed it goes to /checkVerification.

After debugging and trying BasicAuthenticationFilter I still get 403 Forbidden.

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/> 
    <b:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

        <security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions='true'>
         <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/loginCheck" 
            authentication-failure-url="/checkVerification" 
            username-parameter="mobile_Number"
            password-parameter="password"
            always-use-default-target="true"/> 
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginCheck" access="hasRole('VERIFIED_USER')"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginSuccess" />
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/RankOption/**" access="hasRole('VERIFIED_USER')"/>
          <security:logout logout-url="/logout"/>
           <security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </security:http>


       <security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false" alias="authenticationManager">
            <security:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider">
            </security:authentication-provider> 
       </security:authentication-manager> 

    <b:bean id="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <b:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.CT.www.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider">

    </b:bean>   

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>



    <b:bean id="personService" class="com.CT.www.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <b:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></b:property>
    </b:bean>

    <b:bean id="personDAO" class="com.CT.www.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <b:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </b:bean> 
<!-- For hashing and salting user passwords -->
    <b:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>   





    <b:bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
        <b:constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager" />
         <b:constructor-arg ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />

    </b:bean>

     <b:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" 
        class="com.CT.www.provider.PlainTextBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <b:property name="realmName" value="http://localhost:8080" />
    </b:bean> 

    <b:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <b:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
        <b:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql:<ipAddress>/testDB" />
        <b:property name="username" value="root" />
        <b:property name="password" value="<password>" />
    </b:bean>

    <!--  Form Validator -->

    <b:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <b:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </b:bean> 


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <b:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <b:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <b:property name="packagesToScan">
            <b:list>
                <b:value>com.CT.www.model</b:value>

            </b:list>
        </b:property>
        <b:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <b:props>
                <b:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </b:prop>
                <b:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</b:prop>
            </b:props>
        </b:property>
    </b:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.CT.www" /> 


    <annotation-driven />

<!--    Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <b:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <b:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <b:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </b:bean>


</b:beans>
```

homePage.jsp

```
<c:url var="login_Var" value="/loginSuccess" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${login_Var}" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="POST">     
                            <table> 
                                <tr>                                    
                                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                        <input type="text" name="mobile_Number" id="mobile_Number_SignIn" placeholder="Mobile number" disabled="disabled"
                                        class="login" 
                                        style="font-size:15px;border:4px;border: 2px solid #c3c5da;height: 35px; border-radius: 4px;font-size: 15px;" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-right:10px;">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password_Id" placeholder="Password" disabled="disabled" class="login" 
                                        style="font-size:15px;border:4px;border: 2px solid #c3c5da;height: 35px; border-radius: 4px;font-size: 15px;">      
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <!--     <input type="submit" name="loginS" value="Log In" id="loginSuccess" style="display:none;" >  -->
                                        <input type="button" id="login" value="Log In" onclick="login_fntn(mobile_Number_SignIn, password_Id, cCode)" 
                                        disabled="disabled" style="padding:3px;font-weight:bold;background-color:white;"/> 

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right:145px;" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="padding-top:5px;">

                                        <a href="#" id="forgotPassword" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:13px;">Forgot your password?</a>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>
                                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                        </form:form>                        

.
.
.
.

function login_fntn(mobile_Number_SignIn, password, cCode){
                var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
                var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");


                var mobi_Number = document.getElementById("mobile_Number_SignIn").value;
                var password = document.getElementById("password_Id").value;
                var cCode = document.getElementById("cCode").value;
                mobi_Number = cCode + mobi_Number;
                /* var json_LogIn = JSON.stringify({"mobile_Number" : mobi_Number , "password" : password });
                 */

                var datum = [];
                 datum.push({
                    name: "mobile_Number",
                    value: mobi_Number
                }); 
                 datum.push({name:"password",value:password});
                   alert(datum.length + "after " + datum[0].value + datum[1].value);
                 jQuery.support.cors = true;
                 $.ajax({

                    url : "/CT/login",
                    type: "POST",
                    /* contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                    dataType: "json",   */
                    cache: true,
                   /*  data: json_LogIn, */
                    data: datum,
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);                        
                    }, 
                    success : function(response){
                        /* alert(response); Mar22016 */
                        //if response = true , make a request to a method that returns home //this alone will make another db call from UI.
                        //else if response = false, show the dialog box of submit verification
                        //else if response = signup, open up the sign up dialog box.

                            if(response=="true"){
                            /*  $.ajax({

                                    url : "/CT/loginSuccess",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                    dataType: "json",   
                                    data: json_LogIn,
                                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                                        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);                        
                                    }
                                });          */             
                                /* alert("here"); Mar22016 */

                                document.getElementById("mobile_Number_SignIn").value = mobi_Number;
                                document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();


                            }else if(response == 1){

                            //user not registered yet. show dialog boxes. // the main reason why I resend the form in above if condition and do verification stuff again is because if successful it returns logical view. if not it will show dialog boxes(using ajax) to sign up users.
                        }
```

PlainTextBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
public class PlainTextBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends 
BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint{

     @Override
     public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
         response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "null");
         response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + getRealmName() + "\"");
         response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
     }
}
```

SomeController.java
If I change following method loginCheck method as GET, still it doesn't work

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String loginCheck(){

        System.out.println("Inside login check");
        return "true";
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginSuccess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginSuccess(){


        System.out.println("Login 2");

    }
```

I introduced BasicAuthenticationFilter because after some diggingup I found this issue may be because of Cross domain request. Please help me. I am struck with this issue for past 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you default target url should be a GET request instead of a post request  and for ajax you should not load the csrf parameter twice it is better two have it in the meta tag alone.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView defaultPage(Principal pricipal,HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("index");
        return model;
    }
 $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
  });
});

<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Comment: Should the authentication-failure-url have GET method?

Comment: The authentication-failure-url should also have get method